# How can I copy a PDF from OneDrive to iBooks using the OneDrive iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, pdf, books, microsoft

I have a PDF file in OneDrive that I would like to copy to iBooks on my iPhone. Usually apps have an option to copy the PDF to iBooks, but apparently the OneDrive app doesn't. I tried pressing the button on the top right corner after opening the PDF in the OneDrive app and then selecting "Share a link", but it doesn't seem like the iBooks option is available there:

[image]

I clicked on More to see if there was an iBooks option that was hidden, but no.

I also tried Open in another app, but nothing happened. The other options in that menu (delete, rename, etc) don't seem to have anything to do with what I want to do.

I also tried opening the PDF online on OneDrive's website with Safari, since Safari usually has an option to copy PDF files to iBooks, but that didn't open it as a PDF file but as a webpage, so copying it to iBooks that way created a screenshot in iBooks and not the actual PDF.

The only solution that I found was sending the PDF to myself by email and copying it to iBooks through the Gmail app, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do.

Is there an easy way to export a PDF from OneDrive to iBooks on an iPhone, preferably directly from the OneDrive app?

Comment: Three dots and then "Open in app" more or less worked for me.  It crashed the OneDrive app the first three times, but after upgrading to the 21017 Aug 25 release, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the PDF, there should be an option called "Open with ..." or "Open in iBooks".

Or after selecting it, click on the 3 dots on the top right, there should be the option "Open in"

Comment: As I said in my question, I tried clicking on the three dots on the top right and clicking on Open in another app, but nothing happened

Comment: I find it strange, in every cloud service there is the download function and then you can open it in Ibooks. Also downloading from Safari and not from app

Answer (score 0):

You tap on the three dots instead of the Share button. After tapping the three dots you will see the option to “Open in Another App”. Tap that and you will see “Copy to iBooks”

Answer (score 0):

If you have IOS 11, you should also have the **Files** app and your OneDrive account should appear as one of the "positions"
If you select the PDF file there and then use the "share" command, "open in iBooks" will be there.
Dunno why it's not available directly from OneDrive (probably it requires an integration that MS still have to provide)

A "longer" path can be to "copy to Files" from OneDrive (it will end in your iCloud storage) and then to "open in iBooks" from the "Files" app